# Why this lambda can be used here where expects a comparator in a Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream

I am new about Lambda, here is what the textbook (*java in nutshell*) says:

> Only certain types are eligible to be the target of a lambda .
> Target types are also called functional interfaces and they must:
>
> - Be interfaces
> - Have only one nondefault method(but may have other methods that are default)

and the book gives me an example :

```java
File dir =new File("/src");
String[] fileList =dir.list((d,fName)->fName.endWith(".java"))
```

I understand this lambda will convert into a `FilenameFilter` interface which is an `@FunctionalInterface` It does match the description in the book

[image]

However I can use lambda here to when the `sort()` is expecting to receive a `Comparator`

```java
        int n =12;
        Function<String,String[]> f = (s) -> {
            String[] ans = new String[n];();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                ans[i] = s;
            }
            return ans;};
        Arrays.sort(f.apply("colin"),(String s1 ,String s2)->{
            return s1.length() - s2.length();});
```

I look over its source code to find `Comparator` is a `@FunctionInterface`
[image]

but it have two nondefault methods `compare` and `equals`.It is different from what the book says.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the second request at the bottom of your (otherwise well-put) question, because SO is not well suited for handling multiple questions in one. Also, I'm afraid the kind of request you posted there isn't particularly well-suited for SO as a whole (general "how do I approach learning X" type guidance doesn't fit neatly into the Questions-and-Answers model it SO is built on).

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm new here, so I don't really understand.Sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`equals` is a public method of `java.lang.Object`. Those methods are explicitly not counted when identifying functional interfaces.

The real, autoritative definition of what a functional interface is (and what can therefore be "implemented" via a lambda) is found in the Java Langauge Specification.

Almost by necessity the definition of what a functional interface is in a guide book will be less strict and not as precise as the one in the Java Language Specification (because the later is written in a language that's not well-suited for initial learning of a concept and much better for creating multiple compatible implementations of the same thing).

See [JLS §9.8 Functional Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) (emphasis mine):

> For an interface `I`, let `M` be the set of `abstract` methods that are members of `I` that **do not have the same signature as any `public` instance method of the class `Object`**. [...]

Comment: It's worth noting that the reason that this method shows up in the interface's JavaDoc at all (as opposed to, say, [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) where it does not) is because Comparator declares it explicitly, for the purpose of adding a more specific JavaDoc to it than the one provided by Object.